# Odoo 8 method resolution order

Tags: odoo, method-resolution-order

i have problems with understanding the inheritance in odoo.
Consider following code in module 1

```
`class pos_order(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'pos.order'
    def create_from_ui(self, cr, uid, orders, context=None):
        super(models.Model, self).create_from_ui(cr, uid, orders, context=context)
        print "1"`
```

and same in module 2, only it prints 2. First module 1 is installed then module 2. As you see in both the pos_order is extended with custom create_from_ui function. If create_from_ui is called now module2 order is called which in turn calls module1 order which in turn calls original. How could I call only the original now (lets say i dont want "1" printed under certain circumstances)?

Cheers and big thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odoo sets up the hierarchy, but then the normal Python rules apply.

If you want to call the original method from module 2, you can import that specific class from the original module, being careful to pass `self` to it, as you're calling the method from the class, not an instance:

```py
from openerp.addons.point_of_sale.point_of_sale import pos_order as original_pos_order

class pos_order(models.Model):
  _inherit = 'pos.order'
  def create_from_ui(self, cr, uid, orders, context=None):
    original_pos_order.create_from_ui(self, cr, uid, orders, context=context)
    print "1"`
```

Comment: Andreas this must be it, i didnt even think of it!:) Thanks

Comment: Another question regarding this issue. I'm trying to call "create" function which is called in the end of original create. I know it sounds weird but pos_order.create  calls another create which leads to some old_api wrapper and returns new order ID `return super(pos_order, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)`. How could i call this create from the newly created module.  I just need to call directly this.  If i call exactly this part of code in new module the original pos_order.create is called, as it has same name. Thank you again

Comment: @detroit Yeah, that's the `create()` that actually writes to the database. That's part of the Model class (the one you inherited from), so you can just call `models.Model.create(self, ...)`

Comment: Andre ....oh my goose...seriously can i be more blind...its obvious since the original is inheriting from the models.Model right?. I wish i could up your answer one more time..thanks!